# How to populate data from a text file saved in sdcard in a string array?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have a text file stored in sdcard.I want to copy the data from text file in sdcard into a string array.I want to store data in string array and then later use that data in my autocompletetextview.My code is:

```
package com.example.pro2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ReadSettings();

            }
        });
    }
    public void ReadSettings(){

        try{             
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sdcard,"comm.txt");        
               FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(file);          
               BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));           
               String readString = new String();                


               String val[] = null;
               for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
               {
               while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                   Log.d("line: ", readString);   
                   val[i] = readString;
                   Log.d("values", val[i]);
                   // u better use an ArrayList or you have to check if i < val.size
               }
               }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {          
               e.printStackTrace();          
            } catch (IOException e){             
               e.printStackTrace();          
        }    
    } 
    }
```

But it is showing force close.Plz help.

Comment: Which line do you have that force close?

Comment: Any logcat output? By the way, just wondering, if you're saving settings in that file, why not use SharedPreferences?

Comment: Why are using while statement inside the for statement?

Comment: first of all, migrate your readsettings() method in to another thread. As a result, you won't block the main thread (which UI operations runs on). This is mandatory, because file I/O operations may take quite a time.

Comment: am getting force close at this line:val[i] = readString;

Comment: Move it to another thread as @GökhanBarışAker suggested.

Comment: Ok i will move to it to another thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possibly an answer, please change here:

```
ArrayList<String> val = new ArrayList();
               int i=0;

               while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                   Log.d("line: ", readString);   
                   val.add(readString);
                   Log.d("values", val.get(i).toString());
　　　　　　　　　　　i++;
                   // u better use an ArrayList or you have to check if i < val.size
```

Comment: Please try my edit. Replace String val[] by ArrayList<String> val

Comment: Yes i will try and let u know

Comment: Log.d("values", val[i]);It is howing an error:"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>"

Answer (score 0):

Try this-->

```
 val[i++] = readString;
```

Instead of 
      val[i] = readString;

Answer (score 0):

String Array is not re sizable  so use string buffer or Arraylist and later on convert it into array ......

you must know in advanced the size of data so that you can initialize the string array with that ie

```
//ArrayList<String>  mArrayList  = new ArrayList<String>();
String abc[] = new String[file size ];
```

or use a ArrayList

```
    mArrayList.add(readString);
    int size =mArrayList.size();
    Object[] m= mArrayList.toArray();
```

m contains your string array use toString to get them one by one as per need